# Owl Carousel Centering Mobile Layout

Tags: javascript, css, owl-carousel, photoswipe

I have a web page formatted with jQuery mobile that utilizes Owl Carousel & Photoswipe and it is giving me trouble when viewed on mobile sizes.  The problem is that when viewed on a portrait sized mobile phone (IPhone 5) the one image that is displayed is off center.  I noticed that there is Javascript applying inline style to the ul with the class of .owl-carousel.owl-theme which sets the display to block.  If I switch this to inline while debugging the page in Mobile view with developer tools in Chrome the one image is correctly centered.  If I try to hard code this into the CSS then all images are stacked on top of one another and you can only click on one image (which is incorrect behavior since there are three images in the carousel/gallery).

Does anyone know what my problem is, and how to solve it so that if viewed from a  mobile device in portrait (when only one carousel image is displayed) the image is centered correctly on the page?  I have other pages with similar CSS for the carousel (though not jQuery Mobile) and when viewed on a mobile device the behavior is correct, so I am stumped!  Thank you for any help given!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this CSS

CSS

```
ul.owl-carousel{
padding:0;
text-align:center;
}
```

hope this helps..

Comment: Close.  the image looks centered correctly in mobile now, but once I switch back to normal browser view in developer tools the three images in the gallery lose the margin between each.  This is a head scratcher.  I am going to hit the hay and check back in tomorrow.  It's late here! :)  Thanks for your help!  That may get me closer tomorrow when I check back in and try again!

Comment: I think I figured this out now.  I didn't use your modified code.  I used what you put before, and removed some CSS that was being applied at a breakpoint.  I super appreciate it!  I will vote for your answer before if you change the code back to what it was. :)

Comment: Thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it. Based on Chandra Shekhar's answer, but it seems the plugin is using divs instead of ul now; also I added a mobile query.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  div.owl-carousel {
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
  }
}
```